# Where is gen_math_ops script in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I read the source code of tensorflow on github and find gen_math_ops is imported.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_math_ops
```

However, i cannot find this script in the whole project and it's also not under the ops folder.

[search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRSCY.png)

[No gen_math_ops under ops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NckBS.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's automatically generated by `tf_gen_op_wrapper_*` rules [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L265).

Also you can use ?? in your IPython notebook to find location

[image: example of screenshot of genmathops]

Answer (score 9):

Yaroslav has the right answer, but the link he provided is now broken. Here's a [correct link to tensorflow.bzl](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl).

In my case, I was interested in the internal workings of gen_array_ops._concat . It turns out that the gen*.py are automatically generated wrappers for the C++ kernels located [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/kernels). You can typically guess the kernel op name, e.g., [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_op.cc) was the one I was interested in.

Answer (score 5):

This file is machine generated.

You can find the generated file in .../site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py

For example, in Mac, you can find it at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answers, if your goal is to inspect the source code, try `inspect.get_source`:

[image]