# Modified tensorflow MNIST tutorial code:Error: logits and labels must be same size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

```
<!-- language:python--> 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Dataset, Iterator

a = [[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0], 
               [0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0],
               [1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0], 
               [1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]]
b =    [[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
               [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0],
               [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0],
               [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]]

hm_epochs = 3
n_classes = 4
batch_size = 4
chunk_size = 8
n_chunks = 4
rnn_size = 128

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_chunks,chunk_size])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def next_batch(a,b,batchSize):
    return [a for _ in range(batchSize)], [b for _ in range(batchSize)]


def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.transpose(x)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
    x = tf.split(x, n_chunks)

   lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)

   outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

   output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

   return output

def train_neural_network(x):

   prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
   cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = 
prediction,labels=y) )
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)


   with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0.0

            for _ in range((1)):

                epoch_x, epoch_y= 
next_batch(b,a,batch_size)

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: 
epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out 
of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:val_signalGen.reshape((-1, 
n_chunks, chunk_size)), y:val_states}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

I am a beginner of learning tensorflow. I modified the code from the MNIST tutorial (https://pythonprogramming.net/rnn-tensorflow-python-machine-learning-tutorial/) by replacing the MNIST dataset by simple arrays.

But, after I run the modified code, I got the error as below:

```
  Caused by op 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at:
 File ".\stackOverflowAsk.py", line 78, in <module>
   train_neural_network(x)
 File ".\stackOverflowAsk.py", line 53, in train_neural_network
   cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = 
prediction,labels=y) )
  File "C:\Users\yongx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1594, in 
softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\yongx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 2380, in _ 
softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    features=features, labels=labels, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\yongx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in 
apply_op
   op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\yongx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\yongx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must 
be 
same size: logits_size=[4,4] labels_size=[16,8]
         [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = 
SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Reshape_1, Reshape_2)]]
         [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", 
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", 
send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_962_Mean", 
tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I had checked that my "labels", which originated from array 'a', is of shape (4x4), but why it turned out to be 16x8?

Appreciate all advice. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the part of the traceback that points out which line is crashing?
Also, you can add "<!-- language:python -->" and it will make your code pretty colors.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption,Noted.. I had added the traceback log. I am a noob, not sure how to put the code in the way of <!-- language:python -->...

Comment: You got the important part, "<!--language:python-->" (without quotes) can be anywhere in a post and it signals stackoverflow's CSS to colorize your code. Works for other languages too. When it's outside of a code block it doesn't show, but still affects the colors. :)

Comment: Two things seem a bit weird. You are not defining what shape your `y` placeholder is, so it must be getting confused somewhere along the way. You might want to explicitly give it a shape. And you seem to be training backwards, you have `def next_batch(a,b,batchSize)` and `epoch_x, epoch_y=next_batch(b,a,batch_size)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening before you ever get to using your `a` and `b` variables. In the traceback you can see where it's happening:

```
Caused by op 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at: 
File ".\stackOverflowAsk.py", line 78, in <module> train_neural_network(x) 
File ".\stackOverflowAsk.py", line 53, in train_neural_network    
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = prediction, labels = y))
```

So you can see your labels are actually coming from `y`--which is initialized as `y = tf.placeholder('float')` and never changed--rather than from `a` as you're never getting to the point in the code where you start using `a`. As for why `y` is seen as [16,8], I'm not sure since [the docs say the default is None](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholderhttps://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) and [the actual code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1599) is [a wrapper for a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783977/where-is-gen-math-ops-script-in-tensorflow). But since you know the shape you need, I'd try making the shape explicit with: `y = tf.placeholder('float', shape=(4, 4))`.