# What does @@ means in the Tensorflow source code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What does @@ mean in Tensorflow source code? For example, in this link
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L19

What follows the @@ symbols seems to be some function names. What is the purpose of including such section in the beginning of the source code?

Besides, in this page, it says the

> tf.placeholder_with_default

is defined in

> tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py

But I cannot find the respected python files in the github repository. Where can I find the source code for this function?
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops

Comment: Note, all the `@@` lines are within a triple-quoted string, they're not actual code. There's probably some documentation generation tool which reads those lines.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. I originally though it was some kind of convention, which I did not know.

Comment: To the second question: "gen_array_ops.py" and other "gen_something.py" files are generated automatically, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783977/where-is-gen-math-ops-script-in-tensorflow