# why tf.divide does not return a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

If I run the following code using tf2

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math as m

print(tf.add(5, 2))
print(tf.multiply(5, 2))
print(tf.divide(5, 2))
print(tf.multiply(tf.add(3, 2), tf.add(14, 32)))
print(tf.multiply(2.54, tf.divide(8, 2.6)))
print(tf.subtract(6.3, 2.1045))
print(tf.pow(3.6, 2))
print(tf.add(1, tf.pow(2, 2)))
print(tf.sqrt(5.0))
print(tf.cos(m.pi))
```

I get this as an ouput

```
tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(10, shape=(), dtype=int32)
2.5
tf.Tensor(230, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(7.815385, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4.1955004, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(12.959999, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2.236068, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(-1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Why only tf.divide does not return a tensor?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; It's probably a bug

If you look at the source, you will see that the `divide()` method returns `x/y`, where the other arithmetic operations return the result as, `gen_math_ops.xx()`.

This is why when you call `divide` with python variables, you just get a python variable. However if you do the same with any other function, you get a proper `tf.Tensor`.

You can see what `gen_math_ops` does by running the following (answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783977/where-is-gen-math-ops-script-in-tensorflow)) in Jupyter for example. `gen_math_ops` is auto-generated so you won't find it in the repo. But in short, it executes these operations in a proper TensorFlow environment.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_math_ops
gen_math_ops??
```

The source for `tf.divide` is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L305-L332). It is probably a mistake. So I'll leave it up to you to raise an issue on Github to fix that. This is a very subtle bug, and can lead to some cryptic difficult-to-debug issues (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

it was a bug. 
ticket created https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39475 and fixed.